# Is it possible to make an element invisible to jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have two input fields fields with the same class, one display:none.  I want to query the value of the input field that is NOT display:none.

EDIT (with example)

```
<div id="Parent1" style="display:none">
  <p>
    <input type="text" class="title" value="">
  </p>
</div>

<div id="Parent2">
  <p>
    <input type="text" class="title" value="this is the one I want">
  </p>
</div>
```

js

```
$('.title').val();
```

Returns blank since the first title class is empty.  I want to ignore the first title who's parent is display:none.

Comment: Regarding your question, your title is quite confusing...

Comment: Add corresponding HTML too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [:visible](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector to select element which are not hidden.

```
$('.class:visible')
```

**Note:**(*from docs*)

> Elements are considered visible if they consume space in the document. Visible elements have a width or height that is greater than zero.
>
> Elements with `visibility: hidden` or `opacity: 0` are considered visible, since they still consume space in the layout.

Comment: To select elements which are not visible, use [:hidden selector](https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/)

Comment: Perfect, thank you.  Changing my js to `$('.title:visible').val();` does the trick

Answer (score 0):

there is a `:visible` selector in jquery (and a `:not()` selector, .i.e `:not(:visible)`)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have two elements, you must iterate trough them and find the hidden one.
I see this process convincing for me:

```js
$('.class_el').each(function(el){
      if(el.hidden)
        //do something
});
```

You can also use the :visible selector, like !$(el).is(':visible') instead of reading the property of the element.

It's your choice!
Cheers!